# I need to build multitable sqlite query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I really can't find a way to build the right request.
That's my database design:
[image]

I need to find the number of albums that the user tagged in when my input is USER_ID.
for example: [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

user Keni with ID 203 tagged in pictures with id 101, 103, 104 all these pictures located in different albums, so if i have the id 203, my output should be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ALBUM_ID) FROM PICTURES WHERE ID IN (SELECT PICTURE_ID FROM TAGS WHERE USER_ID = 201);
```

replace the 201 with the desired ID.

Answer (score 0):

A user is owner of albums;
Each album has many pictures;
A picture has many tags;
A user can tag himself in any picture;

Now, the question is: how many albums a user has pictures tagged?

(203 is the USER_ID.)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS CNT 
FROM 
  ALBUMS A INNER JOIN PICTURES P ON P.ALBUM_ID = A.ID
  INNER JOIN TAGS T ON T.PICTURE_ID = P.ID
WHERE
  T.USER_ID = 203
```

Comment: Nope(. when i added to album with id 1 and tagged there user 203 the output is 4. But should be 3, because these 4 pictures located in 3 different albums.

Comment: I see. I think we need to change the count to ```count(A.*)``` or even ```count(distinct(A.ID))```, since we're counting Albums, doesn't matter how many tags in that Album. Can you give a try on that?